# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I am using a Angular 2 app and a NodeJS API. When I had the API in localhost everything was working just right, but I published my NodeJS API to a real server and it gives me that error when I try to access to any method of the API:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I was checking some anwsers from another topics here in stackoverflow and nothing has worked for me.

I've this snipped :

```
app.use(require("cors")());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,responseType"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

So I have the "*" in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header why I got the error that I don't have this header in my headers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using both a some other CORS module, and manually setting your headings?  Fix that, and also show us the full request/response.

Comment: As the other comment says, it appears you're trying to use both the CORS middleware and set the headers yourself, you shouldn't set the headers yourself, and instead use middleware. Here's a [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) to the documentation on setting that up. You're liking have issues due to the pre-flight check from Angular.

Comment: @Brad so should I remove the headers that I inserted manually and just stay with the app.use(require("cors")());?

Comment: @technogeek1995 I already tried that solution and deleted the headers that I set manually but the error is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use only the middleware

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

[more details](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)